# alternative javascript code construction

Tags: javascript, phpbb, phpbb3

i'm using this code:

```
<span style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; background-color: #99ccff; color:#fbfbfb; padding :0px 2px;">
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
var myOldString = '1,2,3,4,5,6<br>1,2,3,4,5,6'
var  myNewString = myOldString.replace(/([0-9]+),?/g,'<span style="padding:5px">$1</span>');
document.write(myNewString);</script></span>
```

The code runs fine in an editor, but on a server it doesn't work the right way (adds padding not to each number but to the whole row).
I also tried adding function, but then I cant add any style to a number (like [u][/u]).

```
"1,2,3,4,5".replace(/([0-9]+),?/g , function (el) {
     return ' <span style="padding:5px">' + el.replace(/,/g,"") + '</span> ';
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: [Works just fine as far as I can tell.](http://jsfiddle.net/0kfr2g4e/) Note that your "padding" style will only work as left- and right-side padding because your `<span>` element is implicitly `display: inline;`

Comment: If you make the inner `<span>` elements also be `display: inline-block` you may get what you want.

Comment: @R.T. I have some rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6[br]1,2,3,4,5,6 and I need: [span style="padding:5px"]1[/span][span style="padding:5px"]2[/span][span style="padding:5px"]3[/span] etc

Comment: @Pointy, dunno why but if I add this code through the bbcode then it doesnt work. Other js codes work fine!

Comment: This site is not a bbcode-based site? I'm not sure what you're talking about. Did you look at [the jsfiddle I linked](http://jsfiddle.net/0kfr2g4e/)?  Your code does in fact generate that markup, but because `<span>` is an inline element you won't get any top or bottom padding.

Comment: @Pointy it's a phpbb3's forum. I'm using bbcode section to add custom bbcode with javascript. U can try it yourself if you have a phpbb forum. And yes I saw your link to the jsfiddle. The code works fine, but as I said it doesn't work on my forum.

Comment: Well you should be able to use your browser DOM inspector to see what actually ends up on the page and how the elements are styled.